# Is there a better way to avoid repeated 'Len == 1' when interpreting booleans from strings?

Tags: c

My solution to string interpretation is pretty fast. However, I worry about repeated `if (Len == 1)`. That might make the function bigger in the executable. How can I improve my function, to not be as redundant while checking if `Len` is equal to 1?

```
#include <ctype.h>
signed char BoolFromStr(const char *const StrIn, register const unsigned char Len) {
    if (!Len || Len > 5 || !StrIn) {
        return -1;
    }
    switch (tolower(*StrIn)) {
        case '0':
            if (Len == 1) {
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        case 'f':
            if (Len == 1 || (Len == 5 && !memcmp(Str+1, (const char[]){'a', 'l', 's', 'e'}, 4))) {
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        case 'n':
            if (Len == 1 || (Len == 2 && Str[1] == 'o')) {
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        case '1':
            if (Len == 1) {
                return 1;
            }
        case 'y':
            if (Len == 1 || (Len == 3 && !memcmp(Str+1, (const char[]){'e', 's'}, 2))) {
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        case 't':
            if (Len == 1 || (Len == 4 && !memcmp(Str+1, (const char[]){'r', 'u', 'e'}, 3))) {
                return 1;
            }
            break;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Is this for an embedded solution, or PC?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I improve my function, to not be as redundant while checking if Len is equal to 1?

Make the *null character* part of the check. `Len` not needed anywhere.

```
// if (Len == 1 || (Len == 5 && !memcmp(Str+1, (const char[]){'a', 'l', 's', 'e'}, 4))) {

if (StrIn[1]==0 || !memcmp(Str+1, (const char[]){'a', 'l', 's', 'e', 0}, 5))) {
// or
if (StrIn[1]==0 || 
    (StrIn[1]=='a' && StrIn[2]=='l' && StrIn[3]=='s' && StrIn[4]=='e' && StrIn[5]==0)) {
```

---

**Bug**

`BoolFromStr(const char *const StrIn, register const unsigned char Len)` is a wrong when the length of the *string* is say 257 and called as

```
const char *s = "ttt....ttt"; // 257 t's
BoolFromStr(s, strlen(s)); // reports 1 even though `s` is not `"t"`.
```

Recommend `size_t` and drop the `register`.  Do not tie the compilers hands.

```
BoolFromStr(const char *StrIn, size_t Len);
```

---

To reduce size and improve speed I'd consider a hashing of the first byte of `StrIn`

```
// Pseudo code

int BoolFromStr(const char *StrIn) {
  const char *tf[] = {"0", "1", "false", "true", "no", "yes", "", "" };
  unsigned hash = hashf(StrIn[0])%8;
  const char *cmps = tf[hash];
  if (StrIn[0] == cmps[0] && (StrIn[1] == 0 || (strcmp(StrIn, cmps) == 0))) {
    return hash & 1;
  }
}
```

See similar [What's the fastest way to interpret a bool string into a number in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63005235/2410359).

Comment: 'const char *s = "ttt....ttt"; // 257 t's
BoolFromStr(s, strlen(s)); // reports 1 even though `s` is not `"t"`.' The issue with that is because in my program it won't be used on strings longer than like five letters

Comment: @user227432 If "it won't be used on strings longer than like five letters" is true then `Len > 5`  test not needed either for this program.  Yet the point of good coding includes re-use and avoiding writing code with too narrow an application.  Keep in mind, tests like `Len > 5` are useful to detect the unexpected as does avoiding type narrowing.  Your call.